# Monitor status query in c#

Tags: c#, power-management, screensaver

I am looking for a way to check the monitor status in C# (.net framework 4.5, win8.1).

(I know impossible to check, the user turn off the monitor manually, I do not want this. I want to check the system(the screen saver) turned it off, or not...)

I found some info about SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, but it is just only about sleep.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "csharp'. Then name is "C#".

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if the screen saver is running by calling the [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and passing it the `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` action.

You'll need a managed prototype for the function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
    SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, ref T pvParam, SPIF fWinIni); // T = any type

const int SpiGetScreenSaverRunning = 0x0072;
```

And to call it:

```
bool screenSaverRunning;
if (!SystemParametersInfo(SpiGetScreenSaverRunning, 0, ref screenSaverRunning, 0))
{
    // some error occurred
}
// screenSaverRunning will be true if the screen saver is running
```